# Issues Visual Studio with WSL debugging for C# ASP.net Core Web APi

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I created standard template ASP.net Core Web API.
I'm trying to run the debugger.

Steps I took:

1. Open Visual Studio make new ASP.net Core Web API and choose file location a folder in wsl. (https checked).
2. Choose WSL in the debugger dropdown and press on it (also tried without debugger).
3. ???
4. Error, displayed below.

```
One or more errors occurred.

Failed to launch debug adapter. Additional information may be available in the output window.

Invalid 'cwd' value '/mnt/\//home/johndoe/www/tmp/ContosoPizza'. The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I was wondering what steps you could take to solve this?

edit:

Versions I am using..;

Visual Studio (2022) version: Version 17.2.0 Preview 1.0
WSL: Ubuntu (20.04)
ASP.net core: 7.0.0-preview.1.22109.13

Comment: Do you get the same error when you create the project in a Windows folder (not folder in WSL), and then choose WSL in the debugger dropdown? That's how I've used it before.

Comment: @Beyers it works perfectly when I create project in a Windows folder.

Comment: @J.Reku I've recently posted about the same issue but no solution yet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71767208/unable-to-debug-wsl2-with-vs-2022-invalid-cwd-value/71777510#71777510